# How to use HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I click in A tag, it doesn't respond or return anything. I'm using Thymeleaf 5 and spring boot 2.

When I change href to `"${'/?sortByPrice='+'ASC'}"`, it still has same result.

Please, help me.

```html
<div class="sort-price">
<select name="">
<option value="" selected="selected">sort</option>
<option value=""><a th:href="${'/?sortByPrice='+ASC}">ASC</a></option>
<option value=""><a th:href="${'/?sortByPrice='+DESC}">DESC</a></option>
</select>
</div>
```

```java
   @GetMapping(value = "")
    public String home(
            Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("productname")ProductVM productName,
            @RequestParam(name = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
            @RequestParam(name = "sortByPrice", required = false) String sort,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            final Principal principal)
    {
        this.checkCookie(response,request,principal);

        HomeVM homeVM = new HomeVM();

//        sort price of the product in home page
        Sort sort1 = by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
        if(sort != null) {
            if (sort.equals("ASC"))
                sort1 = by(Sort.Direction.ASC,"price");
            else
                sort1 = by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"price");
        }
// product getter setter
        model.addAttribute("vm",homeVM);
        model.addAttribute("page",productPage);
        return "/home";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` in `select` `option` doesnt work. One approach is to have a `<form>` tag and your filters inside that:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
  <select name="sortByPrice">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Sort</button>
</form>
```

In this way when you click on Sort form will be submitted to the URL present in the browser with the params present in the `form`

Comment: it will work. But I want to use httpservletrespone to reload the page when selecting a tag.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. Under the hood you are still using `HttpServletResponse`. But if you mean you want to do it asynchronously using Ajax, then its a different approach

Comment: when I click into href, it should reload that page and return "localhost:8800?sortByPrice=ASC". But it doesn't. What should I call that?

Comment: Then put your `href` outside the `select` Rest is fine